# Opening Windows Form app from .bat file places it behind Windows Explorer

Tags: c#, winforms, batch-file

I have the following files:

```
run.bat
bin\myApp.exe
```

The run.bat has some lines that do some needed stuff before finally calling the bin\myApp.exe.

The problem is that when I double-click the run.bat via Windows Explorer, the application opens **behind** the Windows Explorer window, instead of in front of it. The end result is that I keep minimizing or dragging the Windows Explorer window to reach my application.

How can I solve it? It's a C# Windows Form application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few options:

[Form.TopMost Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Form.Activate Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Or combination of those:

```
this.Show();
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
this.BringToFront();
this.Activate();
```

Comment: Form.TopMost did it. Thank you. :)